# Keep data of embedded forms on invalid data posted

Tags: php, forms, symfony

In my symfony 3.2 project I'm using embedded collection of forms with the ability of adding more (or remove) throught JS.

Eveything works fine except handling form errors (on server side). If for some reason the user can submit a wrong data passing throught client-side validation it would go throught server validation and returned to form view. So far so good. The problem is all data the user entered is cleared and he has to type all of it again.

This is only happening with collections of embedded forms. Is this the common behaviour? Is there any way to solve this?

I can add some code. I think it's a pretty standard form:

```
$entity = $er->find($id);
$form = $this->createForm(PlanningChecklistType::class, $entity);

$form->handleRequest($request); 

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {...}

return $this->render(':planning:edit.html.twig', ['form' => $form->createView()]);
```

Comment: Could you add your entity and your form ?

Comment: First off, your title is incorrect.  There is no redirect when invalid data is posted.  Important to understand this because if there was a redirect then all your posted data would be lost and everything would start fresh.  There should not be anything strange about using a form collection.  Take a look at what is actually being posted (use your browser debug tools if necessary or the web tool bar) and verify the expected collection data is being posted.  That will at least cut the problem in half.  Also, verify that a form with valid data works as expected.